Relativistic corrections to Mandelstam variable $t$
a book (Quantum Electrodynamics by Akhiezer and Berestetskii, 2nd ed. pp. 522) claims that when evaluating a Feynman diagram for Moller scattering, the $\frac{1}{q^2}$ in the matrix element $(\bar{u}_{1'}\gamma_{\mu}u_1)(\bar{u}_{2'}\gamma_{\mu}u_2)\frac{e^2}{q^2}$ where $q=p_{1'}-p_1=p_2-p_{2'}$ can be expanded in an approximate equation (which I assume is accurate up to order $m^{-2}$ given the context but I am not clear).
$\frac{1}{q^2}=\frac{1}{\mathbf{q}^2}+\frac{1}{4m^2}+\frac{(\mathbf{qp_1})(\mathbf{qp_2})}{m^2\mathbf{q}^4}$.
I assume that $\mathbf{p_{1,2}}$ and $\mathbf{q}$ are meant to be dotted together. Is anyone able to derive this equation or give any geometric insight as to why a relativistic correction to this Mandelstam variable would have this dot product form?
I ask as it is part of a derivation for obtaining a semirelativistic formula (accurate to order $(p/m)^2$) for the above matrix element in terms of Pauli spinors rather than Dirac spinors.

Are the masses of all the incoming and outgoing fermions the same?

Yes, it's all electrons

I think I should first address the main misconception here. The Mandelstam variables are defined in a relativistic framework, therefore there can be no relativistic corrections to them. What the book is showing you is not a relativistic correction, but an expansion of a relativistic quantity (the Mandelstam variable t) on the non-relativistic limit.
Now, regarding the derivation of the formula, it is quite easy to show that, assuming the $(-,+,+,+)$ metric, the following relation holds
$$\frac{1}{(p_1 - p_2)^2} = \frac{1}{\vec{q}^2} + \frac{1}{4m^2} + \frac{(\vec{q}\cdot \vec{p}_1) (\vec{q} \cdot \vec{p}_2)}{m^2\vec{q}^4}$$
with $\vec{q} = \vec{p}_1 - \vec{p}_2$ and $m_1 = m_2 = m$.
However, with your definition of $q$ I don't think the relation is correct.

I see, then maybe the textbook has an error though it describes this quite clearly: https://imgur.com/a/4jV36kI , however I tried to derive what you've written and I didn't at all see how that was easy to show.

It took me a while to actually derive what you've left, the key thing I suppose I hadn't noticed is that after expanding the q_0 term, you can use that q^4 = (p1^2-p2^2)^2 - 4 (q.p1)(q.p2) (for 3-vectors q,p1,p2).

@user2188518, yes indeed the relation you write is needed. It is still possible that the book is indeed correct but I don't see why right now.
